# EF Core 2.2 LINQ query issues on EF Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I am running into some issues upgrading to EF Core 3.0, queries that run fine on 2.2 are not running on 3.0. E.g below query:

```
      var grpedClientData = (from o in db.TicketEvent
                                   where o.ClientId != null && o.SiteId != null && o.DateUtc >= dateHourUTC && o.DateUtc < toDateUTC
                                   group o by new { o.ClientId, o.SiteId, o.OperatorId, o.TicketTypeId, o.ScannerId, o.ClientBookingId, o.TicketSaleOrderId, o.TicketSaleOrderEntryId } into g
                                   select new StatsSummarySiteVisit
                                   {
                                       DateHourVisitedUtc = dateHourUTC,
                                       SiteId = (int)g.Key.SiteId,
                                       OperatorId = g.Key.OperatorId,
                                       ScannerId = g.Key.ScannerId,
                                       TicketTypeId = g.Key.TicketTypeId,
                                       ClientId = g.Key.ClientId,

                                       NumUnique = g.Where(t => t.TicketEventType.IsPermittedEntry).Select(t => t.TicketId).Distinct().Count(), //issue is here

                                       NumNonUnique = g.Count(t => t.TicketEventType.IsPermittedEntry),

                                       NumRejectedUnique = g.Where(t => t.TicketEventType.IsDeniedEntry).Select(t => t.TicketId).Distinct().Count(), //issue is here

                                       NumRejectedNonUnique = g.Count(t => t.TicketEventType.IsDeniedEntry),
                                       IsLocalIdcard = false,
                                       DateLockedUtc = lockDateUTC,
                                       ClientPreBookingId = g.Key.ClientBookingId,
                                       TicketSaleOrderId = g.Key.TicketSaleOrderId,
                                       TicketSaleOrderEntryId = g.Key.TicketSaleOrderEntryId
                                   }).ToList();
```

I am getting the following error:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'AsQueryable(Where(
>       source: NavigationTreeExpression
>           Value: default(IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType1, Nullable, Nullable, Nullable, Nullable, Nullable, Nullable, Nullable>, TicketEvent>)
>           Expression: (Unhandled parameter: e),
>       predicate: (t) => t.TicketEventType.IsPermittedEntry))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

Grateful if someone could offer their help on this in particular on how to rewrite it so that it works on 3.0.

Comment: I think you probably ran into some LINQ expression that cannot be translated (now) to SQL. Perhaps you should report it to Microsoft, so that they can work on it on a future release.

Comment: The query works on LinqPad 6 which uses LINQ to SQL but not on Visual Studio which is using EF 3.0

Comment: LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework, any kind, are totally unrelated. They use different engines to translate LINQ to SQL. Even in different EF Core versions, there are significant differences in the engine.

Comment: @Tommy you already had a bug, and expressions that can't be translated to SQL. EF would throw an exception but the ancient LINQ to SQL would just load everything in memory and filter them there which is BAD. EF disabled this. Unfortunately, EF Core 1.0, for some unfathomable reason,  brought client-side evaluation back. Thankfully, they removed it again, so now you know you have a perf killing bug in your code

Comment: @Tommy another change is that a single LINQ query now either translates to a single SQL query or it fails. In previous versions, EF Core would execute multiple queries behind your back. That's bad. The query you used here would require either  *multiple* queries or *very convoluted* subqueries in the SELECT clause, or `SUM(CASE WHEN)` clauses instead of `COUNT` with conditions. You can't have `COUNT` with conditions. Even with raw SQL you'd have to rewrite this, possibly using CTEs or views to simplify the query

Comment: @Tommy and unless `TicketEventType` is part of the GROUP BY clause, you can't use it in the SELECT clause at all. The EF Core 2.2 query you run never GROUPed anything